# Convert SqlDataSource to DataTable and DataView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have the following `SqlDataSource` and I want to convert it to `DataView` and read a column from it:

```sql
SELECT     
    dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.UserQuiz.Username) AS [Number of Participants]
FROM         
    dbo.Divisions 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.employee ON dbo.Divisions.SapCode = dbo.employee.DivisionCode 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.UserQuiz ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.UserQuiz.Username 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Quiz ON dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID = dbo.Quiz.QuizID
WHERE     
    (dbo.Quiz.QuizID = @QuizID)
GROUP BY 
    dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut
```

This `SqlDataSource` lets the user enter the number of the Quiz, and it will retrieve the total number of participants in that quiz. I want to convert this `SqlDataSource` to a `DataTable` and read a column from it.

**So how to do that?**

Comment: What you have is a SQL statement, not a `SqlDataSource`. Do you have any code for the creation of your `SqlDataSource` that is not working?

Comment: Reading a columns is not the issue after conversion into datatable

Answer (score 19):

To get datasource

```
SqlDataSource SqlDataSource1 = new SqlDataSource(connectionString, selectQuery);
```

After you got a data source say `SqlDataSource1`

```
DataSourceSelectArguments args = new DataSourceSelectArguments();
DataView view = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(args);
DataTable dt = view.ToTable();
```

Now you can read a column easily from this dt(DataTable) e.g.

```
int columnNumber = 0;
for(int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[i][columnNumber].ToString());
    //Console.log(dt.Rows[i][columnNumber].ToString());
}
```

[Reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/a0d1bbbc-27b1-41c9-b14f-7c5be2c9e33f#39e551e5-1714-45c6-b732-1125704cfc38#39e551e5-1714-45c6-b732-1125704cfc38)

Answer (score 6):

The SqlDataSource has a Select method which you can call to get back a DataView from your SqlDataSource - see the [MSDN documentation on that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.select%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
SqlDataSource dataSource = new SqlDataSource(connectionString, selectSql);
DataView view = (DataView)dataSource.Select(args);

DataTable table = view.ToTable();
```

Is that what you're looking for??