# one asp chart with two datasources

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a problem! I have to write a programm with a chart. After a click on one radiobutton, the datasource of this chart should change from SqlDataSource1 to SqlDataSource2, is that possible to do that? If yes, how can I do this? Please help me out, THX!!

Answer (score 0):

For example:

1. Create two DataTable (dtsource1 & dtsource2)
2. Radio button event (switch from dtsource1 => dtsource2)
3. Refresh your chart with current datatable.

You should have a function to refresh Chart like this:

```
void BindChart(DataTable dt)
{
    //your function.
}
```

Comment: Convert Datasource to DataTable Reference  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452763/convert-sqldatasource-to-datatable-and-dataview